# Dynamic Data : How to bind specific column value into dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, asp.net-dynamic-data

I'm working on a project of type "ASP.NET dynamic data LINQ to LINQ application".

When i execute my application I'm getting all labels and DropDownLists dynamically binding.

I'm referring [this](http://www.shubho.net/2011/03/customizing-dynamic-data-application.html) blog.

Now I need to populate those DropDownList based on my criteria. Currently, it is populating all the records which is there in table for that column. How can I customize this DropDownList like I want to select only User with `Mak` name?

I guess i need to made some linq query here when dropdown populated values? not sure

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (DropDownList1.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                if (Mode == DataBoundControlMode.Insert || !Column.IsRequired)
                {
                    DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("[Not Set]", ""));
                }
                PopulateListControl(DropDownList1);
            }

            SetUpValidator(RequiredFieldValidator1);
            SetUpValidator(DynamicValidator1);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you are using "ASP.NET Dynamic Data `LINQ to LINQ` application". As far as i know and it follows from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee845452(v=vs.100).aspx that there are `LINQ to SQL` and `ADO.NET Entity Framework` technologies that are used to generate data models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to customize data in `DropDownList` control in Dynamic Data site you should use `FilterUIHintAttribute` class (in your metadata) that allows to replace (or add new filters) default (`built-in filters templates`) filters.

Consider example of implementing new filter template **using built-in filter template** for columns of `Boolean` type (as in the attached picture).

Let's suppose that you have table `WorkFlows` with column `Status` of `Boolean` type (`bit` for SQL Server) and you would like that `DropDownList` control has only `false` value (by default user can choose filter value from *All, True, False,*
and *[Not Set]* if the column allows null values).

First of all copy built-in filter template `Boolean.ascx` (you can find it in `~\DynamicData\Filters` directory) and then paste one to the same directory. Then rename new filter to `StatusBoolean.ascx`.

Then you can edit code-behind of `StatusBoolean.ascx` and delete line with

```
DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("True", Boolean.TrueString));
```

Then you should change metadata for `WorkFlows` entity:

```
[FilterUIHint("StatusBoolean")]
public bool Status { get; set; }
```

That's all.

More information at [FilterUIHintAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.filteruihintattribute.aspx).

You can also look my post at [ASP.NET Dynamic Data automatically populating a Drop Down list based on Metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16146497/asp-net-dynamic-data-automatically-populating-a-drop-down-list-based-on-metadata/16211566).

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that the data type you are binding is a nullable bool (bool?). When assigning the DataSource property, you can use `myObjects.Where( o => o.TheNullableBool.HasValue )`.