# ASP.NET Dynamic Data automatically populating a Drop Down list based on Metadata

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

I am using ASP.NET Dynamic Data and one thing I would like to do is to have a meta class, for example:

```
    public class CopyTermsHolidaysMetadata
    {
        [Required]
        public int SchoolID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [UIHint("AcademicYear")]
        public int AcademicYear { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Recipient School")]
        [Required]
        public int DestinationSchoolID { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, the two field SchoolID and DestinationSchoolID are drop down lists which come from the "School" table.

Is there any attribute which I can use to automatically populate these as the drop down lists that they are?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `FilterUIHintAttribute` class that allows to replace (or add new filters) default filters on the `CopyTermsHolidays` entity.

For example:

```
[Required]
[UIHint("AcademicYear")]
[FilterUIHint("AcademicYearFilter")]
public int AcademicYear { get; set; }
```

where `AcademicYearFilter` is custom filter which need to be located in `~\DynamicData\Filters` directory (`AcademicYearFilter.ascx`).

More information at [FilterUIHintAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.filteruihintattribute.aspx).

I will take courage to attach to my answer filter template lookup algorithm and some
citation from *ASP.NET Dynamic Data UNLEASHED*:

> Compared to the lookup rules for field templates, lookup rules for
>   filter templates are simple. Dynamic Data uses only the FilterUIHint
>   associated with the column and has an intrinsic knowledge of several
>   column types. If the FilterUIHint is not specified in the data model,
>   and the column is Foreign Key (a column that represents the parent
>   navigation property of a many-to-one or a one-to-one association in
>   the child entity), a Boolean, or an enumeration, Dynamic Data chooses
>   a predefined FilterUIHint value, ForeignKey, Boolean, or Enumeration,
>   respectively. Having the FilterUIHint value, Dynamic Data tries to
>   locate a user control with the matching name in the
>   DynamicData\Filters directory of the web application project. If the
>   user control does not exist, the lookup process ends, and filtering is
>   considered to be unsupported for this column.

[image]